# Migrate Swift 3 to Swift 4.2 and now I get nil on IBOutlet

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift4.2

I converted and corrected an IOS Xcode project from Swift3 to Swift4.2. It was a very hard time but now that get all building errors resolved I'm getting errors when testing the App ( Yeeeeah... )

When the app try to use am Iboutlet it shows the next crash :

**Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file**

The Code is this :

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import JLSlideMenuController
import Alamofire

class PrincipalViewController: JLSlideNavigationController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewWeather: UIScrollView!
    
    @IBOutlet var profileImage:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var lblUserName:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var menuButton:UIButton!
    var jsonVar:JSON!
    var rutasDisponibles : [Ruta]!
    var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    var viewDayArray = [UIView](repeating: UIView(), count: 7)
    var labelDayArray = [UILabel](repeating: UILabel(), count: 7)
    var labelTempDayArray = [UILabel](repeating: UILabel(), count: 7)
    var ivDayArray = [UIImageView](repeating: UIImageView(), count: 7)
    
    var taskDescargaKmls : URLSessionTask!
    var contador = 1
    
    @IBOutlet weak var btMisRutas: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btRutas: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btInfoMunicipio: UIButton!
    
    var jlSlide: JLSlideNavigationController!
    
    lazy var session : Foundation.URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        config.allowsCellularAccess = false
        let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        return session
    }()
    
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        
        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
        profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        let lang = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "LANG");
        btRutas.setTitle(Languages.translateText("rutas", language: lang!), for: UIControl.State())
        btInfoMunicipio.setTitle(Languages.translateText("info_municipio", language: lang!), for: UIControl.State())
        btMisRutas.setTitle(Languages.translateText("mis_rutas", language: lang!), for: UIControl.State())
        
        if(!OnlineStatus.isConnectedToNetwork()){
            scrollViewWeather.isHidden = true
        }
        
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func sideMenu(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if menuIsPresented(){
            self.hideMenu(animated: true)
        }
        else{
            self.showMenu(animated: true)
            
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.incentea.ocorgo.background")
        
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PrincipalViewController.closeMenu(_:)))
        gesture.delegate = self
        self.parentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture) // The crash here
        ...
```

I try to delete the DerivatedData, clean and build the project aaaaand nothing at all. Try to removing the parentview link with the storyboard and link again and nothing. The same error always. And it's in all IBOutlet elements. On Swift3 has values but on Swift4.2 has nil.

This code was working on Swift3 without crashes. The problem appeared when converting to Swift4.2.

Someone knows how to get through this awfull error?

Sorry for the english...

Comment: Try to reconnect outlets after migration also check if they are exist in interface builder

Comment: How do you create the `PrincipalViewController`?

Comment: is parentview a outlet from the view in another controller or in the same viewController.

Comment: @gbk I try to delete and connect again the outlet and nothing. I check the storyboard and the elements are in there...

Comment: @PhillipMills I don't create it. It's a project for an old partner and the only thing I do is replicate the entire project and make minor changes to database and images. Never has problems until this time because the convert to Swift 4.2

Comment: @kjoe yes. It's a view from the same controller. But it happens in all outlets from the same view.

Comment: Let me re-phrase: How does the app create the instance of `PrincipalViewController` that is causing the crash?

Comment: @PhillipMills Load after the user tap on a button in the first screen "Login" ( second if we have the splash on mind ).
This is the code (I quit the at sign before IBAction for issues with Stackoverflow):

`IBAction func invitado(_ sender:UIButton) {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "INVITADO")
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginINVITADO", sender: sender)
}`

Comment: Check in your storyboard to be sure that the destination controller for that segue has the correct class assigned to it.

Comment: @PhillipMills I have a : Show segue "loginINVITADO" to "Principal View Controller" on the Login (what I think it's OK...) but in the Segue Action has nothing marked on instantiation. Principal View Controller Scene has the Principal View Controller class correct

Comment: Try to clenup project or maybe even derived data after migration and check

Comment: @gbk Thank for the idea but try that already and I put that in the question below the code.

Comment: Check class and module assigned in IB; override loadView and check whats going on; override initWithCoder to make sure that controller is created from interface; add didSet for props to see whats goin on - maybe somewhere in code nil assigned to props

Comment: @gbk I found the problem. There is a pod named JLSlideMenuController and it's very obsolete ( without updates from 2016 ). Has UIViewController on his class and for some reason when It's from there, just returns everything on the storyboard as nil. If I quit the Class from the Pod and use UiViewController directly works.
Now I am try to repair the pod or found a replacement.